# Dockerize PyQT5 GUI applications on Windows 11-qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display $DISPLAY

Tags: python, windows, docker, qt, pyqt5

I have a PyQT5 project. I want to dockerize it. But i getting error:

***qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display $DISPLAY
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.***

There are 3 files in the project folder. These are: Dockerfile,main.py,requirements.txt

Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

RUN adduser --quiet --disabled-password pyqt_user && usermod -a -G audio pyqt_user
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-pyqt5

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

Docker run :

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -u pyqt_user python3 main.py
```

How can i solve this problem.